# jQuery: Post data from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm posting a form via ajax which has the class "bookroom_ajax", the ajax result is returned in a separately div with the class "ajax_response", this is working fine.

But I want to return the results inside the same form it is submited from, but if I add the ajax response class to the form it doesn't work any more:

```
<form class="bookroom_ajax ajax_response">
```

Here's the jQuery ajax code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).on("click",'#bookingbutton2', function() {

    $('.ajax_response').html('<img src="http://mailgun.github.io/validator-demo/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: AJAX_URL,
        data: $('.bookroom_ajax').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            if (response.status == 'success') {
                $('.bookroom_ajax')[0].reset();
            }

            $('.ajax_response').html(response.content);


        }
    });

});

});
```

Comment: what is output if you console.log(response)?

Comment: 200 OK - There don't seem to be any errors, but the loading.gif just keeps displaying and no results are output

Comment: see what is there in response.content by doing console.log(response.content);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your AJAX response doesn't contain expected data. Here's why. As soon as the button is clicked, you change the content of the form to be a loading spinner. Since `bookroom_ajax` and `ajax_response` both point to the same element, your serialized data probably doesn't contain what you expect it to contain (because there are no form elements inside the form any more). As a result, your server doesn't respond the way you expect it to and doesn't contain the data you are trying to put back inside the form element with `.html()`.

```
$(document).on("click",'#bookingbutton2', function() {

    // Form content replaced by a spinner
    $('.ajax_response').html('<img src="http://mailgun.github.io/validator-demo/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: AJAX_URL,
        // Form doesn't contain data, so serialization doesn't result in expected data to be sent to the server
        data: $('.bookroom_ajax').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            if (response.status == 'success') {
                $('.bookroom_ajax')[0].reset();
            }

            // Response doesn't contain expected data 
            $('.ajax_response').html(response.content);


        }
    });

});
```

That is my hypothesis based on the analysis of your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks you're correct, ah I'm so stupid! I've added the loader code after the ajax call and now it works fine.